# res.cookie not setting cookie in browser on some accounts

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies

Hey guys so I have the following request sent as text to my post route : `{ JSON: '{"company":"OmarCompanyTestDev_1","token":"3c87d2345c637627d4c45a39de0362444001b222","email":"support47@support.com","devices":[{"width":200,"height":200}],"first_name":"support user","last_name":"for OmarCompanyTestDev_1"}' }` This one only works sometimes but all my variables get assigned and it redirects as it should.

However this request works every time without fail.

```
 { JSON: '{"company":"NewCompany2","token":"8674f778db4d1e58d5f1fedea4e5fa90ceffc9c2","email":"support69@support.com","devices":[],"first_name":"support user","last_name":"for NewCompany2"}' }
```

heres the code that I am running in nodejs. I dont seem to get any errors the cookie just doesn't set on the first request. I don't understand what is different between the two. All the variables assign and all the logs work but the cookie does not set.

```
router.post("/banner-login", async (req, res, next) => {
  function insertDisplay(displayName, userId, width, height) {
    database.query("call insertDisplay(?, ?, ?, ?)", [
      displayName,
      userId,
      width,
      height
    ]);
  }
  try {
    console.log("request body", req.body);
    const bannerJson = JSON.parse(req.body.JSON);
    const {
      company,
      email,
      token,
      devices,
      first_name,
      last_name
    } = bannerJson;
    console.log("bannerJSON", bannerJson);
    console.log("company", company);
    console.log("email", email);
    console.log("token", token);
    console.log("devices", devices);
    console.log("first_name", first_name);
    console.log("last_name", last_name);

    const username = company.replace(/ /g, "_");
    console.log("username", username);
    const password = process.env.BANNER_USER_PASSWORD;
    const userIdResult = await database.query("call getUserIdByUsername(?)", [
      username
    ]);
    const exists = userIdResult[0][0];

    if (exists) {
      const userId = userIdResult[0][0].id;
      await database.query(
        "update users set banner_token=" +
          database.escape(token) +
          " where id=" +
          database.escape(userId)
      );

      await database.query("call deleteDisplaysByUserId(?)", [userId]);
      devices.forEach(item => {
        let displayName = item.width.toString() + "x" + item.height.toString();
        insertDisplay(displayName, userId, item.width, item.height);
      });
    } else {
      const userAttributes = [
        {
          Name: "given_name",
          Value: first_name
        },
        {
          Name: "family_name",
          Value: last_name
        },
        {
          Name: "email",
          Value: email
        },
        {
          Name: "phone_number",
          Value: "+1234567890"
        },
        {
          Name: "custom:company",
          Value: company
        },
        {
          Name: "custom:role",
          Value: "banner"
        }
      ];
      await cognito
        .signUp({
          ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
          Username: username,
          Password: password,
          UserAttributes: userAttributes
        })
        .promise();

      const params = {
        UserAttributes: [{ Name: "email_verified", Value: "true" }],
        UserPoolId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
        Username: username
      };
      await cognito.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params).promise();
      const confirmParams = {
        UserPoolId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
        Username: username
      };
      await cognito.adminConfirmSignUp(confirmParams).promise();

      const plan = "FREE";
      const dbPlanName = plan !== "FREE" ? "Braintree" : plan;
      const isDisplayOwner = 1;

      const [[{ insertId }]] = await database.query(
        "CALL insertUser (?, ?, ?, ?)",
        [username, dbPlanName, isDisplayOwner, token]
      );

      const paramsId = {
        UserAttributes: [
          {
            Name: "custom:CE_user_id",
            Value: insertId.toString()
          }
        ],
        UserPoolId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
        Username: username
      };
      await cognito.adminUpdateUserAttributes(paramsId).promise();

      // login
      const userId = insertId;

      await database.query(
        "update users set banner_token=" +
          database.escape(token) +
          " where id=" +
          database.escape(userId)
      );

      await database.query("call deleteDisplaysByUserId(?)", [userId]);
      devices.forEach(item => {
        let displayName = item.width.toString() + "x" + item.height.toString();

        insertDisplay(displayName, userId, item.width, item.height);
      });
    }
    const data = await cognito
      .initiateAuth({
        AuthFlow: "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
        ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        AuthParameters: {
          USERNAME: username,
          PASSWORD: password
        }
      })
      .promise();
    const { IdToken, AccessToken, RefreshToken } = data.AuthenticationResult;
    const encryptedIdToken = crypto.encryptTokenPayload(IdToken);
    const encryptedAccessToken = crypto.encryptTokenPayload(AccessToken);
    res.cookie("token", {
      IdToken: encryptedIdToken,
      AccessToken: encryptedAccessToken,
      RefreshToken: RefreshToken
    });
      res.redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("there was an error", error);
    next(error);
  }
```

});

Any help here would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what happened is the size of the cookie was too large for some instances. Cookies only can hold 4096 bytes. In some instances my cookie data was much larger than that and the cookie would not set. In order to fix this I split the cookie information into multiple cookies. Hope this is helpful to someone else out there.